# How turn off automatically generation js after save?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

After each saving files `.ts` typescript generates js in the same directory.

How to turn off this option in tsconfig?

Comment: Typescript itself does nothing like that. Most likely it's your ide or some editor plugin. Or you (or your ide) started tsc with the watch parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you [check out the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) for tsconfig, specifically the `compileOnSave` option. If you want generated js to live in a separate directory, you can specify that with the `outDir` compiler option.

Comment: It is another option `compileOnSave`. In another project  I have `"compileOnSave": true`, but it does not create js files in direcrtories, that I need

Comment: Which editor are you using? I know the option is supported in Visual Studio and VSCode, but not sure about any other editors. I'm also not quite sure what your exact goals are as far as where code should be generated. If you post a separate question and provide more information then maybe I can help.

Comment: I use Visual Code